# Make Airflow worker quit after N tasks have been completed?

Tags: python, airflow

Is there a way to force an Airflow (https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow) worker to automatically quit after a set number of tasks have been completed? A similar parameter exists for the scheduler (`--num_runs`).

Comment: Num runs will exit after set number of dag runs are completed for the dags in the DagBag Folder. There is no task level control in Airflow scehduler. Please elaborate on the question if you meant something else

Comment: yep; i'm after something similar. i'm running my workers as docker containers and it would be useful for the worker to complete say 1000 tasks, and just terminate once it's worked through its allotment (and let docker restart another worker).